# How to structure message and update functions with a variable number of UI elements in Elm?

Tags: elm, elm-architecture

Greetings StackOverflow!

Suppose I have an Elm app with a variable number of text input fields. I'd like to reflect the state of these input fields in the model.

Model and view are easy enough: View just has a `Array String` field in it somewhere.

The view is then computed simply by calling `List.map (HTML input ...)` on that list of strings.

However, I'm a bit lost how to do the update function and message type.

The message could be somethign like this:

`type Msg = InputFieldUpdated Int String`

Here, the Int refers to the position in the Array that the string to be updated has. However, if I do it this way, I can create messages that refer to non-existant array positions simply by setting the Int to something that is out of range.

For a fixed number of input elements, one can solve this problem very elegantly by simply using a union type with a different value for each input, but what about my situation? In the domain of "making impossible states impossible", is there some trick for that that I'm missing?

Comment: What you have described is common enough. You need not worry about array index out of bound errors in Elm because `Array.get` returns a `Maybe a` value.

Answer (score 4):

> However, if I do it this way, I can create messages that refer to non-existant array positions simply by setting the Int to something that is out of range.

According to the documentation of [`Array.set`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Array#set), the array stays untouched if the index is out of range.

Please, have a look at this [ellie-app example](https://ellie-app.com/3cDw7rNCjx6a1). It mostly models the problem, that you've described. Array of elements is rendered and the elements can be added dynamically:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div [] (toList (Array.indexedMap viewElement model.elements))
        , button [ onClick Add ] [ text "Add" ]
        ]
```

In order to update a particular element, you need to get it by index. Since the type of the result from [`Array.get`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Array#get) is `Maybe a`, type system will force you to process all the cases (when the element exists and doesn't):

```
Increment index ->
    case get index model.elements of
        Just element ->
            { model | elements = set index (element + 1) model.elements }

        Nothing ->
            model
```

The example is just for demonstration purposes, if you don't need the current element, then [`Array.set`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Array#set) function can be safely used.